# cannot retrieve values from database django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a table I am trying to retrieve values from. It has two foreign keys and that is it.
I use get_or_create on the table and create an object. I verify with the admin panel that the object is there. Then, I try to retrieve it but I do not get the values even though I can see them in the admin panel.

Here is the table:

```
class req(models.Model):
    to = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "request sent"
```

In the piece of code below, I am retrieving from the database and I try to display it as it is in the p tag(html). In the template, I tried {{ req.to }} and {{ req.from.first_name }} but in vain, I did not see any values when html is rendered.

```
def get(self, request):
        u = get_user(request)
        try:
            my_requests = req.objects.get(from=u)
        except req.DoesNotExist:
            fr = None
        if fr == None:
            return redirect(reverse('myapp:index'))
        if my_requests != False:
            context_dict['req'] = my_requests
        return render(request, 'myapp/req.html', context=context_dict)
```

Can anybody see the problem that I cannot and comment ?

Comment: Not sure what `get_user()` is. I think you can use `request.user` instead. Then, since from is not unique and could have more than one object for the same user, you should use filter instead: my_requests = `req.objects.get(from=request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code. here is the updated version which address your issue :-

```
def get(self, request):
    req_obj, created = req.objects.get_or_create(from=request.user)
    if created:
        context_dict['req'] = my_requests
        return render(request, 'myapp/req.html', context=context_dict)
    return redirect(reverse('myapp:index'))
```